# get index column of duplicate rows based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get ID and person name from the below table where address1, address2, state, city, country columns have same data for all the roles.

| ID | Name | Address1 | Address2 | State | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AB | AB@123 | AB@345 | st1 | ct1 |
| 2 | AB | AB@123 | AB@345 | st1 | ct1 |
| 3 | CD | AB@123 | AB@345 | st1 | ct1 |
| 4 | EF | EF@123 | AB@345 | st1 | ct1 |

I want output as

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AB |
| 3 | CD |

`select ID, Name, count(*) from person group by address1,address2,city,state having count(*) > 1;`

which is giving the exception : not a group by expression.

Please suggest a better approach to achieve about output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT ID, Name, Address1, Address2, State, City
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         COUNT(DISTINCT Name) OVER (PARTITION BY Address1, Address2, State, City)
           AS cnt,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY Address1, Address2, State, City, Name
           ORDER BY id
         ) AS rn
  FROM   person p
)
WHERE  cnt > 1
AND    rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (ID, Name, Address1, Address2, State, City) AS
SELECT 1, 'AB', 'AB@123', 'AB@345', 'st1', 'ct1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'AB', 'AB@123', 'AB@345', 'st1', 'ct1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'CD', 'AB@123', 'AB@345', 'st1', 'ct1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'EF', 'EF@123', 'AB@345', 'st1', 'ct1' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAME | ADDRESS1 | ADDRESS2 | STATE | CITY |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | AB | AB@123 | AB@345 | st1 | ct1 |
> | 3 | CD | AB@123 | AB@345 | st1 | ct1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=66849901eb081cb9cfc5deae7d5cb211)*